# tar only the file in the directory

Tags: linux, archive, tar

How to tar only a file present in the directory. I have tried `tar -cvf /tmp/test.tar /tmp/mylog.doc` being in home diretory,but when I untar it the contents included `tmp`directory too. I need only the file `mylog.doc` to be present in the tar file. I see the similar query
[Tarring only the files of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710146/tarring-only-the-files-of-a-directory). but could not get much help from it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `-C` command line parameter to indicate the directory you wanna work in. Then, you can use the filename you include relative to this directory.

```
tar -cvf /tmp/test.tar -C /tmp mylog.doc
```

Note that this does not apply to the tar file itself.

Comment: It did not work. `tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive` `Try tar --help or tar --usage for more information`

Comment: `tar` simply says that it cannot find the file `mylog.doc` in the directory `/tmp`. Is the file actually there?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd sourcedir ; tar cvf archive.tar ./file_to_tar
```

because using "/path/to/file"  or  "./path/to/file"  : will add "path/to/" in the resulting tar file (unless specific (and also probably non-portable) options telling tar otherwise)

note: some not-so-old production system also still can't get rid of the leading "/" when extracting.

On those 'not-so-old' systems:

```
tar cvf /tmp/hosts-backup.tar /etc/hosts
cd /secure/location
tar xvf /tmp/hosts-backup.tar
```

will *overwrite* the file /etc/hosts, instead of outputing a "./etc/hosts" file underneath /secure/location ! (as most 'recent' tar now do : they now all silently ignore the trailing "/", making the path relative instead of absolute, which is what 99.9% of people want)

I've been burned recently with this : wanted to extract a log, and that log ended up overwriting the original location (and thus overwrote the more recent log file there). Always check for this before using tar for the first time on a system. (there are a few workarounds, but not too simple : chroot, and other commands such as "sar")